# Como pegar o caminho da subpasta que foi " SELECIONADA " na listbox pelo usuário e salvar o arquivo dentro

Tags: c#, winforms

O programa que estou criando deve fazer os seguintes passos:

1. Primeiro o usuário cria uma subpasta para ir salvando os projetos que foram calculados pelo programa, conforme imagem e código abaixo.
2. Quando o usuário cria uma subpasta, por exemplo “EM01_Projeto de um bloco 4”,
   ela é criada dentro de um diretório pré-definido (c:\evandro\tad\“EM01_Projeto de um bloco 4”)
3. Como faço para salvar um arquivo onde o nome já fixo no código escrito em C# “Cargas.txt” onde quando o usuário dá um click no botão “Salvar”, conforme imagem abaixo, e este comando reconhece o caminho da subpasta aberta ou criada através do textBox_NomeBloco.Text pelo usuário final conforme explicado no item 2?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tad_Bloco1._0
{
     public partial class NovoBloco : Form
     {
        string[] listapasta = Directory.GetDirectories(@"c:\evandro\tad");        

    public NovoBloco()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void NovoBloco_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        foreach (string p in listapasta)
            listBox_ListaBlocos.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(p));

    }

    private void button_Ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        string pasta = @"c:\evandro\Tad\" + textBox_NomeBloco.Text;

        if (Directory.Exists(pasta) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(pasta);
            listBox_ListaBlocos.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(pasta));
            MessageBox.Show("Pasta criada com sucesso!");
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Esta pasta já existe");
    }

    private void button_Cancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private void listBox_ListaBlocos_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox_NomeBloco.Text = listBox_ListaBlocos.Text;
    }
  }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Explica melhor, pelo menos pra mim a pergunta não está fazendo sentido.

Comment: Boa noite Daniel                                                                                          Como faço para criar um código para salvar um arquivo onde o nome já é fixo no código escrito em C# “Cargas.txt” onde quando o usuário dá um click no botão “Salvar”, este comando reconhece o caminho da pasta aberta ou criada pelo usuário final conforme explicado no item 2.

Comment: No método `button_Ok_Click` você salva a última pasta cria no `listBox_ListaBlocos`, certo? Se for isso mesmo, o último registro desse `ListBox` é a última pasta criada: `listBox_ListaBlocos.Items[listBox_ListaBlocos.Items.Count - 1];`

Comment: Isso mesmo Daniel

Comment: O problema era só esse? Seu problema já foi resolvido então? A parte de salvar o `txt` você conseguiu?

Comment: Desculpe Daniel na verdade o listBox é só para o usuário visualizar qual e quantas pastas ele tem. A última pasta está no textBox_NomeBloco

Comment: Na verdade `textBox_NomeBloco.Text` tem a pasta selecionada no `ListBox`, não?
Enfim, se o seu problema já tiver sido resolvido, apague a pergunta, porque ela não está muito boa.

Comment: Daniel eu reformulei a pergunta, talvez acredito que deve estar mais clara!

Comment: Realmente, consegui entender bem o que seu programa deve fazer, mas agora você não está falando sua dúvida. Qual sua dúvida? Qual sua dificuldade em fazer o que você listou lá em cima?

Comment: O código lá em cima esta ok. A minha pergunta é como criar um código no segundo forms (a segunda imagem) onde quando eu clico no botão "salvar", este reconhece a subpasta que foi criada pelo usuário no textBox_NomeBloco.Text e salva o arquivo fixo "Carga.txt".

Comment: Sinceramente eu acho que você não tem uma dúvida, você quer que alguém aqui faça o seu trabalho pra você. Recomendo estudar um pouco de `c#` e `Windows Forms`, está cheio de tutorial na internet pra isso: http://bfy.tw/6ICZ

Comment: [Retornar array PHP no JSON em AJAX](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135271/45854)

Comment: Como já falei não sou programador e sim engenheiro civil, só estou desenvolvendo este programa para uso pessoal. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @EvandroMendes Tudo bem que você não seja programador,mas mesmo assim,dê uma pesquisada melhor sobre o assunto que tem dúvidas,caso não encontre,você pode perguntar,mas não querer esperar que outros façam tudo para você.

Answer (score 2):

Acho dificil alguém formular isso aqui para você, não achei a pergunta muito clara e foi muito especifica a ponto de realmente parecer que você está pedindo o código pronto a alguém... bem, eu não entendi a pergunta mas vou tentar ressaltar alguns pontos....

- Você pode escrever um txt com esse simples comando
- System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\exemplo.txt", "conteúdo");

Se a questão é um botão numa Form secundária salvar um arquivo que está de alguma forma contido na Form Primária você pode tentar usar uma variável Global
Definindo uma variável como "public"
vamos supor que a Form Main deve chamar a Form Exemplo passando pra ela uma string... existem mais de uma forma de fazer isso, tentarei lhe mostrar a mais simples...

```
public class Main : Form
{
    public Main(){
        InitializeComponents();
    }
    public void Button1_Click(object o, EventArgs e){
        Exemplo form = new Exemplo();
        form.Caminho = "C:\Exemplo.bin";//aqui é onde a Form Exemplo salvará
        form.Conteudo = "Conteúdo de Exemplo";//aqui é o conteúdo a salvar...
        form.ShowDialog();
    }  

}
public class Exemplo : Form
{
    public string Caminho;
    public string Conteudo;
    public Exemplo(){
        InitalizeComponents();
    }

    public void Salvar_Click(object o, EventArgs e){
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Caminho, Conteudo);
    }

}
```

Bem, acabei dando meio de mão beijada mas é isso ai... eu prefiro passar o argumento direto pra form, mas acho que isso é mais fácil pra tu

Comment: Marcus André, Falion  muito obrigado pela ajuda de vocês. Eu vou tentar resolver de outra maneira e assim se conseguir obter sucesso no meu código vou colocar aqui. Provavelmente eu  acho que não foi bem clara a minha pergunta, então acho melhor tirar e assim que terminar o código eu insiro aqui. A respeito do meu comentário sobre eu não ser um programador profissional, só respondi desta forma porque fiquei chateado a forma como o nosso amigo Daniel respondeu.

Comment: @Evandro Mendes E aí colega. Conseguiu resolver? Se sim, posta o resultado. Você disse que postaria...