# Retornar array PHP no JSON em AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, json

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
function atualizaPainelQtdeReservas(){ 
     var dataFiltro = $(".dataFiltro").val();

     $.ajax({  
          url: "crud/painelQuantidadeReservas.php", 
          dataType: 'html',
          data: {dataFiltro:dataFiltro},
          type: "POST", 

         success: function(data){
              $('#resBusca1').html(data[1]);
         },
     });
};
```

E

```
 $dataFiltro = $_POST['dataFiltro'];
 $data = implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$dataFiltro)));
 $select = "SELECT SUM(numeroPessoas) as total FROM Reserva
            where data = '$data'
            group by hora
            ";
$conexao = conexao();
$PDO = $conexao -> prepare($select);
$PDO -> execute();

$total = array();
while ($obj = $PDO -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $total[]= $obj->total;
}
echo json_encode($total);
```

O SELECT retornará os dados: 9, 6, 2

Quero retornar no success o array com os resultados, porém como fiz no $('#resBusca1').html(data[0]) o que me retorna é um [

Caso eu faça:

```
 success: function(data){
 for(var i in data) {
     document.write(data[i]);
 }
 },
```

o mesmo retorna ["9","6","2"]

Cada resultado (9,6,2) quero retornar em um id no html.
Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Estás a usar `dataType: 'html',` devias usar `dataType: 'json',`.

Comment: Opa, obrigado, resolveu.
E se eu precisar de um array multiplo, como poderia fazer?

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo desse json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para leitura de array multidimensionais, poderá ler no `success` do AJAX, estipulando é claro o `dataType: 'json'`, com o `$.each`:

```
success:function(resposta){
   $.each(resposta, function(i, resp){
      // agora é colobar resp.indice que obterá o valor do índice correspondente no array json 
   })
}
```